# Single result for each database and group results by database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hey guys I'm an amateur at SQL but I have spent several hours looking for how to do this and as far as I can tell, no one has described it (at least not to the point that I can understand).

I have a SQL query that I need to run against each of the 45 (non-system) databases on my server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 IdTransaction, IdDateTime, ArchivedDate, RetentionCategoryIdentity
FROM Saveset
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM HoldSaveset 
    WHERE saveset.SavesetIdentity = HoldSaveset.SavesetIdentity)
```

Since this query only returns one result, I would like to group those results by database name.  If it makes things easier, I am only *really* interested in "ArchivedDate".

Comment: In SSMS, you can reference each database and table using the `.` notation.  eg. `select * from [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]`  You can then use `UNION ALL` to concatenate the results of each query into one large result set.  Optimizing further you could generate the sql in a loop and run `EXECUTE` on it.

Comment: I believe you 100% - the problem is that I have no idea how to construct such a statement to run against all non-system databases (or all databases with some error handling for db's which don't contain the subject table).  Sorry for being the annoying noob here.

Comment: So just to clarify, you'd like the script to work without knowing the names of the various databases ahead of time?

Comment: Correct.  Or, if necessary, I can list the databases since they are static but I was under the impression that running a query against multiple databases was possible using a table (extent of my knowledge).

Comment: There are system tables that would allow you to query your database names ([`sysdatabases`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179900.aspx) for example.  Using this table you would loop its results and build the sql as a big string, then execute it as i described earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query sys.databases, using some kind of filter on the NAME field, to insert all of the database names you want into a Table Variable. Include a sequential field that can be used for looping. The code for that would look something like this.

```
DECLARE @MyDatabases TABLE (DbName VARCHAR(500), RowNum INT IDENTITY(1,1))
INSERT INTO @MyDatabases (DbName)
SELECT name
  FROM sys.databases
 WHERE name LIKE '%filter names here%'
```

Once the databases you want are in a Table Variable, you can loop through the table, executing a Dynamic SQL Statement once per database in the Table Variable and Inserting the results into a temp table. Once the loop is complete, you can select all of the values from the temp table for your final results. The code to perform this would look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyData (ArchivedDate VARCHAR(100), DbName VARCHAR(500))
DECLARE @CurrentDatabase VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Counter INT = 1

WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM @MyDatabases)
BEGIN
   SELECT @CurrentDatabase = DbName
     FROM @MyDatabases 
    WHERE RowNum = @Counter

   SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #MyData(ArchivedDate, DbName)
               SELECT TOP 1 ArchivedDate, ''' + @CurrentDatabase + '''
                 FROM ' + @CurrentDatabase + '.dbo.Saveset a
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @CurrentDatabase + '.dbo.HoldSaveset b WHERE a.SavesetIdentity = b.SavesetIdentity)'
   EXEC(@SQL)

   SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

END

SELECT * FROM #MyData
DROP TABLE #MyData
```

Code explanation: This code first creates a Temp Table called #MyData with the Archived Date field (since that's what you said you were most interested in). Then declares a @CurrentDatabase variable to hold the value of the current database in the loop. It then declares a @SQL variable used for the Dynamic SQL Statement. Then declares the @Counter variable used for the looping process.

The next line begins the Loop process. Once inside the Loop, the @CurrentDatabase is set by selecting the next sequential database from the table variable @MyDatabases. Then the Dynamic SQL Statement is set using the @CurrentDatabase variable. Then the Dynamic SQL Statement is executed, inserting the results of the Dynamic SQL String into the Temp Table.

Lastly, the counter is incremented. Once out of the loop, all results are selected from the Temp Table. And finally, the Temp Table is dropped.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this up.  It looks perfect for what I need and very well laid out. I do, however, get an error (twice) stating:
Invalid column name 'RowNum'.
at lines 12 and 16

Comment: My mistake, I had RowNum labeled as RowCounter in the first section of code at the top. I corrected it. Should be good now.

Comment: Ok, I also added a period before dbo.HoldSaveset on line 20 to get my results but I need to also get the database name in the table as well. I guess I should have said the items I'm most interested in are ArchivedDate and the database from which the query came - sorry.

Comment: I updated the period before dbo.HoldSaveset and modified the #MyData table to include a new column for DbName. I then modified the SELECT statement in the Dynamic SQL String to include the @CurrentDatabase which will now be inserted into the #MyData table and should appear in the result set. If this completes your query, please mark the question as answered, or let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  This may seem trivial to you but it is a phenomenal help to me and I very much appreciate your patience and help!

Comment: I hate to ressurect this issue but for some reason the query is manipulating the results I'm getting. My original query, run against one db, returns what seems to be the raw data from the table like so: "2014-04-09 17:36:00.000" which I like.  The loop query is returning the date in a modified format: "Apr 9 2014  5:36PM"  Any idea why?

Comment: Not 100% sure. Since there are 45 databases involved, it may be a COLLATE issue on one or more DB's, so all results are being converted as such. Either way, instead of doing SELECT * FROM #MyData, you can do SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ArchivedDate,120) AS ArchivedDate, DbName FROM #MyData. The 120 is a predefined format. See the link below for various formats and you can use whichever you like.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL to create your select statement. Just put your desired table name in the @targetTable variable. It will create a table that stores your results. Hope this helps! If you have any questions, just let me know!

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX),
        @targetTable VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @sql = 'select top 1 IdTransaction, IdDateTime, ArchivedDate, RetentionCategoryIdentity ' + 
        'FROM '+ QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.Saveset AS A '
        + 'where NOT exists (Select * from ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.HoldSaveset AS B ' + 'WHERE A.SavesetIdentity = B.SavesetIdentity) UNION ALL ' + COALESCE(@sql,'')
FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE NAME NOT IN('master','tempdb','model','msdb')


SET @targetTable = 'database.schema.tablename'
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @targetTable + ' FROM (' + SUBSTRING(@sql,0,LEN(@SQL) -8) + ') A';

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was too lazy to write! :) +1.  Probably want to put an exec on the sql at the end.

Comment: Yea I think it's missing something, I get "Command(s) completed successfully".

Comment: Try adding `print @sql` or `select @sql` at the end.

Comment: man, I missed my last line in copying and pasting it. Sorry. Try it now.